# University Probability - Distance between Random Variable and Constant

Tags: probability

Suppose that the average distance between a random variable X and a constant c is measured by the function E(X − c)^2. (Note that E (X − c)<sup>2</sup> can be viewed as a function of c: Q (c) = E (X − c)<sup>2</sup> .)

(a) Show that E(X − c)<sup>2</sup>  = E (X − EX)<sup>2</sup>  + (EX − c)<sup>2</sup>

(b) What value of c does minimize E (X − c)<sup>2</sup>

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is an identity. It can be proved by expanding both sides, and using the linearity of expectation.

We do the harder of the expansions, and leave it to you to do the other two. We have
$$E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-E(2XE(X))+E((E(X))^2).\tag{1}$$
Leave the first term alone. Note that $2E(X)$ is a constant, so $E(2XE(X))=2E(X)E(X)=2(E(X))^2$. Finally, since $E(X)$ is a constant, we have $E((E(X))^2)=(E(X))^2$. Putting things together, we find that the left side of (1) is equal to
$$E(X^2)-(E(X))^2,$$
a formula that you will use over and over again in your work in probability.

For part (b), we want to minimize $E((X-E(X))^2)+(E(X)-c)^2$. We have no control over the first term. The second, being a square, is always $\ge 0$, and reaches a minimum of $0$ if we pick $c=E(X)$.